# Kendo Grid: Server side pagination without a "total"

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

With the particular database server we are using it's just as expensive to run a COUNT() query as it is to run the actual query, so I'd prefer to not display the count at all.

Normally, outside of kendo grid, I would just display previous and next buttons but not show the total count. Is it possible to achieve something similar with Kendo Grid?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set the numeric property of the pageable object in your kendo grid options. That should disable the numeric buttons for you:

```
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  pageable: {
    numeric: false
  }
});
```

See http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#configuration-pageable.numeric for more info

To set the data to a specific count, in your kendo datasource options, use the schema.total function to return some large value to give you enough paged data:

```
var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
  schema: {
    total: function(response) {
      return 100000000;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: It's a bit hacky, but when you're using someone elses UI framework nothing is ever perfect.